# How to show enumeration value of variable, rather than the bit vector value in ModelSim

Tags: simulation, modelsim

I'm currently working on a final project for my Verilog course, which involves building a processor. As part of this project, I've created a state machine, and I'm trying to visualize the names of the states in the waveform window.

However, it seems to display the state values by default instead of their names. Could you advise on how I might adjust this to display state names instead?

This is how it looks in my Modelsim window:

[image: waveform caputure]

The names of the states are:

```
parameter T0=0, T1=1, T2=2, T3_reg_io=3, RB0_HLT=4, T3_mri=5, D0T4=6,
D0T5=7, D1T4=8, D1T5=9, D2T4=10, D2T5=11, D3T4=12;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Modelsim you can add FSM using the following steps:

1. Use FSM recognition and FSM coverage options (`+acc`, `+cover`) during compilation,
2. Use the `-fsmdebug` and `-coverage` options on the vsim command line.

Check [ModelSim User's Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/131619-modelsim-user) for more details. Notice that using `View > FSM list` you can check all FSMs detected by ModelSim and add it to a wave.